# process a signal from a .wav and turn it into binary data

Tags: signal-processing, fft, signals

I recorded a radio signal into a .wav, I can open it in audacity and see that there is binary data encoded using a certain algorithm. Does anyone know of a way to process the signal that is contained within the .wav? so that i can extract the binary data from it?

I know that I need to know the encoding algorithm for it to work properly, anyone know of any program that does something like that?

Thanks

Comment: You already have a binary file with audio samples.  What exactly do you want to do?  A good start, as you noted, would be to figure out the exact container and codec.  A likely possibility is [LPCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_pulse_code_modulation) in a [Waveform Audio File Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) (a form of [RIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format)) file.

Comment: You should see different components in the FFT -- carrier frequencies, baud rate, and products of each other.  If you know the format your life will be a lot easier.  To decode 4-level-FSK, use FIR (finite impule response) digital filters.  An FFT window will be too coarse to decode at the baud rate, but an FIR might be able to.
  If you got the signal off of a scanner, look up 'trunktracking' to get some leads into demodulating your signal, whatever it may be.

Comment: This is heavily dependent on the kind of modulation of the data.  There are numerous possibilities.  For example, weather satellites use one method.  Pagers another.  PSK31 is different from RTTY.  And so forth.

Answer (score 1):

[sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) will convert most audio formats to most other audio formats - including raw binary.

Comment: sox is what I uses to perform the reverse operation; it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The .wav format is generally very simple and wav files usually don't have compressed data.  It's quite feasible to parse it yourself, but much easier to use something already made.  So the short answer is to find something that can read wav files in your language of choice.

Here's an example in Python, using the [wave](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html) module:

```
import wave

w = wave.open("myfile.wav", "rb")
binary_data = w.readframes(w.getnframes())
w.close()
```

Now where you go depends on what else you want to do.  `binary_data` is now a python string of the raw bytes.  If you just want to chop this and repackage it, it's probably easiest to leave it in this form.  If you want to manipulated the data, such as scale it, interpolate, filter, etc, you would probably want to convert this into a sequence of numbers, and for this, in Python, you'd want to convert it to a [numpy](https://numpy.org/) array.  You could do this yourself using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module, which is for interpreting strings as packed binary data, or you could just have read in the data using [scipy.io.wave](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html#scipy.io.wavfile.read) module which does this for you.  As you can see, most of this becomes fairly language dependent quickly.